# Помогите разобраться с индексацией массива в javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с индексацией массива arr в следующем примере (учебное упражнение, реализующее рулетку):

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>

var arr = [];
var rounds = 100;
var zero = 0;
var i = 0;

for(i=0; i<=rounds; i++) {
    arr.push(Math.round(Math.random()*36));
}

alert(arr);

for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i]==0) {
        zero++;
    }
}

alert("Вероятность выпадания зеро: "+zero/arr.length*100+"%");

</script>
```

Все в принципе понятно, за исключением единственного момента: условие в теле второго цикла, которое проверяет наличие zero `if(arr[i]==0)`. Почему i, которая ранее в коде была обьявлена как обычная переменная, использовалась в качестве счетчика и никоим образом не была связана с массивом arr, внезапно стала его индексом по которому проверяется наличие нуля. Спасибо!

Comment: потому что в качестве _счетчика/индекса_ может использоваться любая переменная

Answer (score 2):

Для доступа к элементам массива используется [*Bracket notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

В квадратных скобках может быть **абсолютно любая строка**, неважно откуда взявшаяся: прописанная напрямую или из какой-либо переменной.

В данном случае используют переменную `i`, так как из-за условий цикла она будет меняться от минимального индекса массива, до максимального, что позволит проверить *все* элементы.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно поняла вопрос, то нужно понять как работает данный цикл.

```
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i]==0) {
        zero++;
    } }
```

В этом цикле вы смотрите наличие `0` в массиве `arr` 
Для этого естественно нужно пройтись по массиву, т.е. перебрать все элементы и сравнить элемент с `0`, и далее по коду.

Короче говоря, вы входите в цикл, присваиваете `i = 0`, смотрите на `arr[0]`, если он равен нулю, считаете, если нет, инкрементируете `i` и повторяете итерацию снова.

Если нет, то думаю стоит уточнить, что именно непонятно и тогда будет проще понять, как с этим бороться)

Comment: Здравствуйте, Darina! Спасибо за ваш ответ! Мне не понятно почему для проверки условия в теле цикла ("равняется ли элемент массива нулю?") используется переменная i, которая в условии цикла работает просто как счетчик. Почему идет именно такая запись (arr[i] == 0)? Ведь в квадратных скобках может быть лишь элементы цикла, которые в данном случае представляют собой циферную последовательность от 0 до 36, а не символы типа i. Может быть я пока просто не совсем понимаю синтаксис, поэтому извините, если вопрос кажется вам глупым. Буду очень признателен, если вы поможете "разжевать" этот момент

Comment: @Михаил, _Ведь в квадратных скобках может быть лишь элементы цикла_ - нет, в квадратных скобках может быть любая строка. _а не символы типа i_ - в данном случае `i` - это не строка, это переменная, в которой хранится какое-то значение

Comment: @Михаил, мне кажется, вы не совсем разобрались в массивах. Переменная i - это переменная, в которой лежит какое-то значение. В данном случае в arr[i] вместо i подставляется ее значение. Если бы хотели подставить символ, делали бы так: arr['i'], но это другая тема. 

Поразбирайтесь еще с массивами, например вот здесь https://learn.javascript.ru/array#перебор-элементов

Comment: @DarinaGoodwill спасибо! Кажется начинаю понимать: т.е. переменная i в данном случае работает как счетчик индексов элементов в массиве. После каждой итерации i становиться на единицу больше (0,1,2,3... максимальное значение индекса, которое берется из значения arr.length). Затем ее значение подставляется в  arr[i] == 0 тем самым перебираю индексы массива. Верно?

Comment: @Михаил, ураааа! Вы поняли! :)
Примите тогда ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае это оптимизация производительности (в данном случае на мой взгляд абсолютно бесполезная, хоть и имеет место быть). `i` объявляется один раз а не 2:

```js
var arr = [];
var rounds = 100;
var zero = 0;

for (var i = 0; i <= rounds; i++) {
  arr.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 36));
}

alert(arr);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == 0) {
    zero++;
  }
}

alert("Вероятность выпадания зеро: " + zero / arr.length * 100 + "%");
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: в данном коде ничего не поменялось по сравнению с кодом в вопросе

Comment: Второй раз писать var для i не имеет смысла

Comment: Так как используется _var_ тут объявится точно так же _одна_ переменная